# Should a Linked Data Platform (LDP) server answer to a request for a container that does not exist in the dataset?

Tags: linked-data, rdf

I'm developing a partial implementation of the LDP specification and I have the following issue:

Suppose that my dataset contains book resources with URIs like: `http://example.org/book/lord-of-the-rings`. If I understand correctly, when a client makes a GET request to `http://example.org/books/`, the server should return a list of books in a LDP container. Does this mean that the dataset have to contain the triples describing this container, or does it have to happen automatically?

The container could look like this:

```
@prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>.
@prefix ldp: <http://www.w3.org/ns/ldp#>.

<http://example.org/books/>
   a ldp:BasicContainer;
   dcterms:title "A container of books";
   ldp:contains <http://example.org/book/lord-of-the-rings>,
                <http://example.org/book/don-quixote>,
                <http://example.org/book/moby-dick>.
```